I get an error when importing anything from react-native-google-signin/google-signin
When I import anything from react-native-google-signin/google-signin, I get this error:
ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleSignin' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","SourceCode","Timing","AppState","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","DevSettings","DevToolsSettingsManager","Networking","Appearance","DevLoadingView","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","DeviceInfo","UIManager","ImageLoader","SoundManager","IntentAndroid","DeviceEventManager"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","RedBox","BugReporting","LinkingManager","RNGoogleSignin"]}, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I create my project using Expo init and use this command to install the library I want, npm i @react-native-google-signin/google-signin.
app.Json:
{
  "name": "ideagenie",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.2.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.26",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.22",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


I am having the exact same issue
